# Creating union/spread of two objects while turning unique property into array of original property object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in need of re-constructing an object that was deconstructed earlier in my code (for Angular UI reasons). Basically, I have objects that there may be multiple copies of, but with one property between them now being different due to user selection, which need to be rejoined into a single object but keeping all unique values of the user-selected field.

I could have, for example, 3 selected objects:

```
{
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: 'group1',
    userSelection: {
      childId: 1001,
      childName: child1
    },
  },
  {
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: 'group1',
    userSelection: {
      childId: 1002,
      childName: child2
    },
  }, {
    groupId: 2,
    groupName: 'group2',
    userSelection: {
      childId: 1001,
      childName: child1
    },
  }
```

I can't figure out how to use the `spread` operator or something like lodash's Union, because I can't just take the final object's `userSelection` and discard the others. I need `userSelection` to become an array of the joined `userSelection`s, to where the above groups would result in

```
{groupId: 1, 
 groupName: 'group1',
 userSelection: [ 
                    { childId: 1001, childName: child1 },
                    { childId: 1002, childName: child2 }
                ],
{groupId: 2, 
 groupName: 'group2',
 userSelection: { childId: 1001, childName: child1 },
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

if the selection data that you mentioned is an array (which I assumed it is in my solution to be able iterate over it), you can use `reduce` with `findIndex` and `spread` operator to achieve this:

We will use an empty array for our result as `acc` of our reducer:

```
data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc, [])
```

Then we will populate the array with selection objects:

```
return [...acc, cur]
```

Here we will make an alteration as well to make the `userSelection` an array:

```
cur.userSelection = [cur.userSelection]
```

Eventually we will encounter duplicates, so that's why we should check it as the first step of iteration:

```
const duplicateIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.groupId === cur.groupId)
```

If there's any, we will create a new instance of `userSelection` and add the `userSelection` object to our own `userSelection` arrat (instead of adding the whole object with `id` and `name` to the result array):

```
acc[duplicateIndex].userSelection = [...acc[duplicateIndex].userSelection, cur.userSelection]
return acc
```

Below is the working solution:

```js
const data = [{
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: 'group1',
    userSelection: {
      childId: 1001,
      childName: "child1"
    }
  },
  {
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: 'group1',
    userSelection: {
      childId: 1002,
      childName: "child2"
    }
  },
  {
    groupId: 2,
    groupName: 'group2',
    userSelection: {
      childId: 1001,
      childName: "child1"
    }
  }
]

console.log(data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const duplicateIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.groupId === cur.groupId)
  if (duplicateIndex !== -1) {
    acc[duplicateIndex].userSelection = [...acc[duplicateIndex].userSelection, cur.userSelection]
    return acc
  } else {
    cur.userSelection = [cur.userSelection]
    return [...acc, cur]
  }

}, []))
```